# httpd-2.2.14 with apache-tomcat-6.0.20

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

Do I need special configuration of these two together to allow my tomcat server to host website(s)?

Comment: What's special? What is your concern?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 6 will work with the apache servers 1.3 or 2.x to run your tomcat site via regular http server port 80.  Documentation on configuring the apache side and tomcat side can be found here:

https://sec1.woopra.com/docs/proxy-howto.html

Redhat Enterprise has the module ready to go in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf

In Debian, it involves the apache module enabler commands such as a2enmod or you can
make the symlinks between enabled directory and available manually.

This site may answer other questions you may have:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors